# What is the ultimate size of a two-dimensional array with float64 components

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have written a **cython** function using `numpy.array` to execute some calculation on a big array for example the array has `24000x1500` size. Then I got `MemoryError`.

I am wondeing what is the ultimate size of a two-dimensional array with `float64` components in python?

Is this error occurring due to the size of my array?

What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python memory usage of numpy arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784329/python-memory-usage-of-numpy-arrays)

Comment: What is the calculation?  An expression involving numpy arrays might result in the creation of several temporary arrays that hold intermediate results.

Answer (score 1):

Since a 64 bit float occupies 8 bytes, you can easily estimate a lower bound at 24,000 * 1500 * 8 = 288,000,000 bytes which is about 0.3 GB. I don't know about the overhead created by a numpy array, but I'm guessing it's not significant for an array that size.

According to the answer I linked to in the comment above, you can also find the size using `arr.numbytes`. It also returns the memory used by the array elements.

I can see how a program using that much memory could throw a `MemoryError`. Do some memory profiling to find out if it's your big array (likely) or something else that eats your memory. Or buy more memory.