# Numpy Matrix Memory size low compared to Numpy Array

Tags: python, numpy, memory

I have a .npz file which I want to load into RAM . The compressed file size is 30MB . I am doing the following operation to load the data into RAM.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import sparse
from sys import getsizeof

a = sparse.load_npz('compressed/CRS.npz').todense()
getsizeof(a)
# 136
type(a)
# numpy.matrixlib.defmatrix.matrix
b = np.array(a)
getsizeof(b)
# 64000112
type(b)
# numpy.ndarray
```

Why `numpy.matrix` object occupy very low memory size compared to `numpy.arrray` ? Both a and b have same dimension and data.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python memory usage of numpy arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784329/python-memory-usage-of-numpy-arrays)

Comment: If you'd used `.toarray()` you'd have gotten the full size.  `.todense` adds a `asmatrix` layer on top of that, creating a view.  That is an implementation detail.  In general `getsizeof` is not a reliable measure.  It sort of works with arrays, but is worthless with lists.

Answer (score 3):

Your `a` matrix is a view of another array, so the underlying data is not counted towards its `getsizeof`. You can see this by checking that `a.base is not None`, or by seeing that the `OWNDATA` flag is `False` in `a.flags`.

Your `b` array is not a view, so the underlying data is counted towards its `getsizeof`.

`numpy.matrix` doesn't provide any memory savings.