# Python pickling and unpickling numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, serialization, pickle

I have the following dilemma. I am trying to pickle and then unpickle a numpy array that represents an image.

Executing this code:

```
a1 = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
print(sys.getsizeof(a1), a1.shape)

a2 = pickle.dumps(a1)
print(sys.getsizeof(a2), type(a2))

a3 = pickle.loads(a2)
print(sys.getsizeof(a3), a3.shape)
```

Produces this output:

```
6220928 (1080, 1920, 3)
6220995 <class 'bytes'>
128 (1080, 1920, 3)
```

Now, `a1` is thus around 6 MB, `a2` is the pickle representation of `a1` and is a bit longer but still roughly the same. And then I try to unpickle `a2` and I get... something obviously not right.

`a3` looks fine, i can call methods, I can assign values to it's cells etc.

The result is the same if I replace pickle calls with `a1.dumps` and `np.loads` since these just call pickle.

So what exactly is the deal with the weird size?

Comment: `sys.getsizeof` is not the right function to use. Try the `nbytes` property of the array. In your case `a1.nbytes`. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#:~:text=All%20built%2Din%20objects%20will%20return%20correct%20results%2C%20but%20this%20does%20not%20have%20to%20hold%20true%20for%20third%2Dparty%20extensions%20as%20it%20is%20implementation%20specific

Comment: `getsizeof` is a tricky tool to use correctly.  It is better for numpy arrays than lists, but still you can get unexpected values.  Here I suspect `a3` is a `view` of something else.  For example `loads` might have created a 1d array, and then reshaped it.  `sys.getsizeof(a3.base)` might give an expected size.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the a3 object does not own the ndarray memory but point it to the a3.base. Thus the sys.getsizeof(a3) won't report the a3.base memory size.

In contrary, a1 object does own it's memory (because a1.base is None, please check the explanation of .base of ndarray by saying help(a1)). Thus the sys.getsizeof(a1) report the memory size including the whole array.

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import pickle

a1 = np.zeros((1080, 1920, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
print(sys.getsizeof(a1), a1.shape, type(a1))
if a1.base is None: 
    print("a1.base==None, The object a1 owns its memory. Thus the size of a1 is ",sys.getsizeof(a1))

a2 = pickle.dumps(a1)
print(sys.getsizeof(a2), type(a2))

a3 = pickle.loads(a2)
print(sys.getsizeof(a3), a3.shape, type(a3))
if a3.base is not None:
    print("a3.base is not None, The object a3 does not own its memory. Thus the size of a3 is ",sys.getsizeof(a3))

help(a1)
```

see more numpy memory usage discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784329/python-memory-usage-of-numpy-arrays).

So depends on what you want to achieve, sometime sys.getsizeof() may not get you an intuitive result. It's primarily depends on what you mean by "object storage".

Answer (score 0):

From the [`sys.getsizeof` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.getsizeof):

> Return the size of an object in bytes. The object can be any type of object. All built-in objects will return correct results, but **this does not have to hold true for third-party extensions** as it is implementation specific.

Emphasis mine. Basically there's no guarantee that `sys.getsizeof` will give you consistent or correct values for numpy objects.

Answer (score 0):

Making the arrays and dump.  It doesn't have to be big.

```
In [15]: a1 = np.zeros((10,20,30)); a2 = pickle.dumps(a1); a3 = pickle.loads(a2)
```

`nbytes` match, as does shape

```
In [16]: a1.nbytes, a3.nbytes
Out[16]: (48000, 48000)    
In [17]: a1.shape, a3.shape
Out[17]: ((10, 20, 30), (10, 20, 30))

In [18]: type(a2)
Out[18]: bytes
In [19]: len(a2)
Out[19]: 48154
```

Since the `getsizeof` for `a3` is so small, I suspect it's a `view` of something.  That is, `getsizeof` does not 'see' its databuffer.

If an array has its own data, the `base` will be `None`.  Or it may be a `view` of another array.  But apparently `loads` has constructed this array by referencing a `bytes` object:

```
In [20]: type(a3.base)
Out[20]: bytes    
In [21]: len(a3.base)
Out[21]: 48000
```

That looks like `a2` without some sort of information header.

Anyways, `getsizeof` is not that useful when examining arrays - or lists.

---

Here's a simpler case, with a common test array:

```
In [22]: x = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)
In [23]: sys.getsizeof(x)
Out[23]: 120
In [24]: sys.getsizeof(x.base)
Out[24]: 152
In [25]: x.base
Out[25]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])
```

`x` is actually a `view` of the array created by `arange`.

### edit

I suspect `a3` is created with something like:

```
a4 = np.ndarray(a1.shape, buffer=a2[154:])
a5=np.frombuffer(a2, dtype='float', offset=154).reshape(a1.shape)
```

Another note - `pickle` lets the object specify how it will be serialized.  For `ndarray` that is done with the `np.save` code.  The format is a header buffer followed by a copy of the array's databuffer.

```
In [35]: np.save('test.npy',a1)
In [38]: !dir test.npy
 Volume in drive C is Windows
 Volume Serial Number is 4EEB-1BF0

 Directory of C:\Users\paul

10/27/2022  05:43 PM            48,128 test.npy
               1 File(s)         48,128 bytes
```